# You must set \"va\" host group when enable \"va\" service - Installation Error

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I'm trying to install IBM Cloud Private CE 2.1.0.2 and receive following error during the installation. I don't understand why it occurs and where I can enable/disable this \"va\" service.
Below is the output from the installation with verbose mode (-vvv):

```
TASK [check : Validating Community Edition] ************************************
task path: /installer/playbook/roles/check/tasks/main.yaml:8

TASK [check : Validating hosts file] *******************************************
task path: /installer/playbook/roles/check/tasks/local.yaml:8

TASK [check : Validating Master nodes number] **********************************
task path: /installer/playbook/roles/check/tasks/local.yaml:13

TASK [check : Validating Proxy nodes number] ***********************************
task path: /installer/playbook/roles/check/tasks/local.yaml:17

TASK [check : Validating master HA configuration] ******************************
task path: /installer/playbook/roles/check/tasks/local.yaml:21

TASK [check : Validating proxy HA configuration] *******************************
task path: /installer/playbook/roles/check/tasks/local.yaml:28

TASK [check : Validating HA VIP configuration] *********************************
task path: /installer/playbook/roles/check/tasks/local.yaml:35

TASK [check : Validating HA Master node interface configuration] ***************
task path: /installer/playbook/roles/check/tasks/local.yaml:42

TASK [check : Validating HA Proxy node interface configuration] ****************
task path: /installer/playbook/roles/check/tasks/local.yaml:50

TASK [check : Validating VA service configuration] *****************************
task path: /installer/playbook/roles/check/tasks/local.yaml:58
fatal: [127.0.0.1 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": true, 
    "msg": "You must set \"va\" host group when enable \"va\" service"
}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=4    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=1   

Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 7 seconds

user@kim:/opt/ibm-cloud-private-ce-2.1.0.2/cluster$
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what caused the error.

In the config file under the "Disabled Managment Services Settings" section "va" can be disabled. 
I copied my settings from the 2.1.0.3 config file to the 2.1.0.2 config file and while the error does not occur for the 2.1.0.3 installation without disabling "va", it occurs when trying to install 2.1.0.2.

To avoid this error message the settings must therefore look like this (default):

```
## Disabled Managment Services Settings
disabled_managment_services: ["va"]
```

For 2.1.0.3 "va" is not a disabled service, since it's not a listed parameter there.